# Random walk - proving limits exist

Tags: probability-theory, random-walk

Consider the random walk $\{X_k\}_{k\geq0}$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ with transition probabilities 
$$\begin{cases}
p_{i,i-1} = p_{-1} &> 0 \\
p_{i,i+1} = p_{1} &> 0 \\
p_{i,i+2} = p_{2} &> 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
and
$$\begin{cases}+p_{-1} + p_1 + p_2 &= 1 \\
-p_{-1}+p_1+2p_2 &\geq 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
while $T_n := \min\{k; X_k \geq n\}$.

**(A) Show the** existence of limits $$\lim_{n\to \infty} P_0(X_{T_n}=n)$$ and  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{P_0(X_{T_n}=n+1)}{P_0(X_{T_n}=n)}$$

**(B) Show that**  $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{P_0(X_{T_n}=n+1)}{P_0(X_{T_n}=n)} = 1 - P_0(X_{T_1}=1)$$ and

**(C) determine** $$P_0(X_{T_1}=1)$$ and $$P_0(X_{T_2}=2)$$

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please, consider updating your question to include what you have tried / where you are getting stuck. You will find that people on this site will be significantly faster to help you if you do that; that way, we know exactly what help you need.